# What is the process for updating the application managed with MDM in the Apple AppStore?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, mdm, airwatch

We have an app managed with "AppConfig-App Configuration" approach. We want to update this app in AppStore. Apple consistently rejects the app. The reason for the rejection is not the errors in the application, but the constant new requests related to MDM. (Provide MDM test environment, provide information on how to download iOS Profiles to the device, show the user a popup that the data collected with MDM is not shared with a 3rd party, etc.) And they want them part by part, and it never ends. But our customers are waiting for app update.
What is the process for updating the application managed with MDM in the AppStore? What is the experience of other people submitting their MDM-managed app to the AppStore?
I would be very grateful if someone with experience in this matter could share their experience with me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll recommend to share the video with apple how th process of the apps happens from distribution to deletion. Regarding the policy you have to share the policy adhering thing so they can rely with the authenticity of the apps data